# PatsyError, name error, name is not defined when using smf.ols

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror, parse-error, smf

I am trying to use multi linear regression to analysis some time series data and their lags. Basically variables are some currency rate and their lag1 and lag2. Code is as below.
I tried to check each variable and there is nothing abnormal..

```
rate = pd.read_csv('P2training.csv', header=0)
#change date format in csv
rate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(rate['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
rate.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
lags = [1,2]
lagdata = rate

for i in lags:
tmp = rate.shift(i).copy();
lagdata = lagdata.join(tmp, rsuffix='_lag{}'.format(i));

#  fit the linear regression models
collist = list(lagdata.columns);
collist.remove('AUD/USD')
collist.remove('GBP/USD')
collist.remove('CAD/USD')
collist.remove('NLG/USD')
collist.remove('FRF/USD')
collist.remove('DEM/USD')
collist.remove('JPY/USD')
collist.remove('CHF/USD')
form = 'JPY/USD' + '~' + '+'.join(collist);
lagdata.dropna(inplace=True)
model = smf.ols(formula=form, data = lagdata).fit()
```

error occurs in last step when using smf.ols. A few name errors said some variables is not defined.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-                 packages\patsy\compat.py in call_and_wrap_exc(msg, origin, f, *args, **kwargs)
116     try:
--> 117         return f(*args, **kwargs)
118     except Exception as e:

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in eval(self, expr, source_name, inner_namespace)
165         return eval(code, {}, VarLookupDict([inner_namespace]
--> 166                                             + self._namespaces))
167 

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'USD_lag2' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PatsyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-1985b8d39238> in <module>()
 51 #print(collist)
 52 #print(lagdata)
---> 53 model = smf.ols(formula=form, data = lagdata).fit()
 54 
 55 #print(model.summary())

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in from_formula(cls, formula, data, subset, drop_cols, *args, **kwargs)
153 
154         tmp = handle_formula_data(data, None, formula, depth=eval_env,
--> 155                                   missing=missing)
156         ((endog, exog), missing_idx, design_info) = tmp
157 

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py in handle_formula_data(Y, X, formula, depth, missing)
 63         if data_util._is_using_pandas(Y, None):
 64             result = dmatrices(formula, Y, depth,    return_type='dataframe',
---> 65                                NA_action=na_action)
 66         else:
 67             result = dmatrices(formula, Y, depth,     return_type='dataframe',

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in dmatrices(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
308     eval_env = EvalEnvironment.capture(eval_env, reference=1)
309     (lhs, rhs) = _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env,
--> 310                                       NA_action, return_type)
311     if lhs.shape[1] == 0:
312         raise PatsyError("model is missing required outcome variables")

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
163         return iter([data])
164     design_infos = _try_incr_builders(formula_like, data_iter_maker,  eval_env,
--> 165                                       NA_action)
166     if design_infos is not None:
167         return build_design_matrices(design_infos, data,

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in _try_incr_builders(formula_like, data_iter_maker, eval_env, NA_action)
 68                                       data_iter_maker,
 69                                       eval_env,
 ---> 70                                       NA_action)
 71     else:
 72         return None

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py in design_matrix_builders(termlists, data_iter_maker, eval_env, NA_action)
694                                                    factor_states,
695                                                    data_iter_maker,
--> 696                                                    NA_action)
697     # Now we need the factor infos, which encapsulate the knowledge of
698     # how to turn any given factor into a chunk of data:

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py in _examine_factor_types(factors, factor_states, data_iter_maker, NA_action)
441     for data in data_iter_maker():
442         for factor in list(examine_needed):
--> 443             value = factor.eval(factor_states[factor], data)
444             if factor in cat_sniffers or guess_categorical(value):
445                 if factor not in cat_sniffers:

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in eval(self, memorize_state, data)
564         return self._eval(memorize_state["eval_code"],
565                           memorize_state,
--> 566                           data)
567 
568     __getstate__ = no_pickling

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in _eval(self, code, memorize_state, data)
549                                  memorize_state["eval_env"].eval,
550                                  code,
--> 551                                  inner_namespace=inner_namespace)
552 
553     def memorize_chunk(self, state, which_pass, data):

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\compat.py in call_and_wrap_exc(msg, origin, f, *args, **kwargs)
122                                  origin)
123             # Use 'exec' to hide this syntax from the Python 2 parser:
--> 124             exec("raise new_exc from e")
125         else:
126             # In python 2, we just let the original exception escape -- better

C:\Users\yaojia\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\patsy\compat.py in <module>()

PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'USD_lag2' is not defined
    JPY/USD~AUD/USD_lag1+GBP/USD_lag1+CAD/USD_lag1+NLG/USD_lag1+FRF/USD_lag1+DEM/USD_lag1+JPY/USD_lag1+CHF/USD_lag1+AUD/USD_lag2+GBP/USD_lag2+CAD/USD_lag2+NLG/USD_lag2+FRF/USD_lag2+DEM/USD_lag2+JPY/USD_lag2+CHF/USD_lag2
```

Comment: my guess is that foward slash is not allowed in the names. workaround use Q() https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q or rename

Comment: you are right. I changed the forward slash and it works. Thank you